# Problem reading multiple Firebase Storage URLs to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, firebase-storage

I'm trying to read multiple image-URLs to an array using Firebase Storage like this, but I am having problems reading specific index positions in the testArray:

```
  var testArray = []

  listAll(ref).then((res) => {
    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
      getDownloadURL(itemRef).then((url) => {
        testArray.push(url) 
      })  
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  }); 

  console.log(testArray[0])
```

What is the correct way of storing the Firebase Storage URLs in an array that will be used later in the code?

Comment: React uses state to store stuff. You need `const [testArray, setTestArray)] = useState([]);` then use Promise.all to get all download urls, then finally use `setTestArray(promiseResult);` to store them in your App state. Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Thanks ChrisG, that was really helpful. I am still having a issue with a loop when printing the array to console. Any idea how I can solve this? I updated the post with the edited code.

Comment: `console.log(testArray[0])` runs long before `setTestArray(urls);` however you can simply console.log(urls) inside the callback instead

Comment: It looks like you were able to solve your own problem, which is always great news.  --- instead of posting it as an edit to your question, can you actually post it as an answer below? Self-answers are encouraged here on Stack Overflow, and have the added advantage that the system also knows that you've been helped.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I just posted it as an answer below Frank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ChrisG's comment, I can now read the array at index-position. Here's the solution:

```
  const [testArray, setTestArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    listAll(ref)
    .then(async (res) => {
      const {items} = res;
      const urls = await Promise.all(
        items.map((item) => getDownloadURL(item))
      );
      
      setTestArray(urls);
    })
  
    .catch((error) => {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }); 
  }, [])

  console.log(testArray[0])
```